# Why does git merge with no conflicts still produce a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, revision-history

I'm trying to understand why git will produce a commit with a unique SHA1 for a merge between two branches with no conflicts. Is storing the information that there were no conflicts really worth the extra clutter to the revision history?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that a commit records a specific state of your working directory, and a merge will create a state that doesn't match either of the parents, so a new commit is required, as opposed to just moving a branch pointer. To elaborate a bit more, though, it helps to understand exactly what it means to merge two branches.

The two most common ways `git merge` is used are to a) catch up a local branch to a remote branch and b) actually merge two separate branches together.

In the first case, you have something like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G
      ^           ^
      |           +-- origin/master
      +-- master
```

In this case, `git merge origin/master` simply moves the pointer for `master` to the new location. This is what's called a "fast forward" merge, and usually does not result in a new commit (although you can explicitly request one if you have a reason to).

On the other hand, if you have something like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G <-- branch1
      \
       J--K--L--M--N <-- branch2
```

and you are on `branch2` and want to merge in `branch1`, simply moving your `branch2` pointer would not make sense. If you just moved `branch2` to point to `G`, you would lose the changes made in `J` through `N`. In this case `git merge` must create a new commit, where the resulting working tree would look like you took a copy of `C` (the merge base of `G` and `N`, which you can see by running `git merge-base branch1 branch2`), and then applied all of the changes in `D` through `G` and in `J` through `N`. Even if this results in no conflicts (the two branches either modified different sets of files or at least just different areas of the files), the resulting working directory state does not match either `G` or `N`, so a new commit is required. So `git` will create a new commit with a working directory that contains the results of applying the changes from both branches, and will mark that commit as having both `G` and `N` as parents.

So, it's not really "storing the information that there were no conflicts", it's storing a new unique state of your project. Sure, you can look at that commit with `git log`, `git diff`, etc. and see that either there were or weren't conflicts, but that's not the reason the new commit was made.

Comment: This explanation makes the most sense to me. (Sorry, @SLaks, I like yours, too, but this gets closer to addressing my line of reasoning.) I was trying to figure out why a `git rebase` would be less suited than `git merge` in a situation with no conflicts. This makes it clear: you would lose the information of your state before the merge. This also makes sense to me as to why fast forward merges do not require a unique commit.

Comment: +1 for being definitive. A minor nitpick (mostly for the OP): a commit is cut from the index (the staging area), not from the work tree, so the merge commit represents the exact state of the index rather than that of the work tree.

Comment: @kostix Yeah, I considered covering more of those gory details, but decided that might make the answer more complex than it needed to be and actually distract from answering the original question. Like many useful systems today, it's actually quite a bit more complex than can easily be described... And `merge` generally updates the work tree anyway, so unless you started with a dirty tree (which `merge` tends to not like), the overall effect is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

The point of a merge commit is to include two different trees of commits in the parent of the resulting HEAD.

There are three possible ways to perform a merge:

1. Create a merge commit with a separate parent for each thing you merged.
   This means that all of the original commits from the branch you merged will still show up in your history as a separate parallel track.
2. Create a fake merge commit with only one parent which contains all of the merged changes.
   This results in a simpler history (no separate tree), but it loses all of the commits of the merged branch.
   This is a bad idea.
3. Create new commits for the merged changes which have the original branch as their parents.
   This results in a linear history with both sets of commits interspersed.
   This is what `git rebase` does.

Comment: Ad 3. just to emphasize - rebase really **does create new commits**. For each commit of rebased branch it will create a new commit with same patch and apply it onto the target branch of the rebase operation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is storing the information that there were no conflicts really worth the extra clutter to the revision history?

You want `git rebase`, which does this. One simple way to think of using rebase to merge and avoid a merge commit is, "pretend that work happened first instead of in parallel."

Rebase can be dangerous to "play with" before git makes sense to you as elegant, but it does solve the problem you have intuited. In general rebase is used when the "raw" commit history does not make sense to you. In the case of a merge, it's used when one of the parent histories you think is irrelevant and should never have really happened (it "rewrites history"). In the case of some major merges, you really *do* want both histories; in others, you don't. I'm omitting a fuller explanation as you can find many online, some better than others.

Comment: as a noob you do not want rebase as it rewrites history. if you know what you are doing, then rebase can solve problems like the one described in the question.

Comment: I generally prefer `git rebase` but I'm trying to understand why `git merge` might be preferable if there are no conflicts.

For the record, when I was new to git, I found `git merge` to be substantially scarier than `git rebase`.

Comment: @mnagel added fuller explanation

Comment: @patrickvacek when you *want* both histories. Rebase squashes history. Trying looking at a complex project in a git UI (e.g. github network) and think of which merges and branching are annoying clutter and which tell you two real branches went into a commit.

Comment: @djechlin `rebase` doesn't always squash history, but it can. Better to say that it rewrites history...